# What is a good technical book to start learning Many worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations

Good books exist on quantum mechanics emphasizing on the Copenhagen Interpretation.What are some good "technical" books on Everettian Many world interpretation of quantum mechanics?
I emphasize on the world technical,because most books I have come across are non-technical ones (although there are many technical papers). But is there a good concise and comprehensive but detailed book to start reading it from?

Answer (score -1):

No, there cannot be. Many worlds is not actually an interpretation of the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics. For example, it uses ideas like "the wave function of the universe" which cannot appear in treatment of the mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics, and it ignores the fact that it cannot explain the Born rule.